# Did Queen's performance really cause Live Aid to clear $1,000,000 in donations?

Tags: realism, historical-accuracy, bohemian-rhapsody

In *Bohemian Rhapsody*, Bob Geldof is shown pleading with viewers to donate money. The phone bank operators are waiting for their phones to ring. Then, Queen gets on stage, the phone banks are busy, and Live Aid clears $1,000,000 in donations.

I expect that most of this is overly-dramatized, but during the actual Live Aid concert, did donations surge during Queen's performance? Did Live Aid clear $1,000,000 during Queen's performance?

Comment: I have to start with "I don't know" but for those watching it live on the day, Queen & U2 were notably brilliant, against the merely 'great' of the rest, so it wouldn't surprise me if they did create an uptick.

Comment: Like many other events in the movie, it was changed to add dramatic license.  Just a few things the movie got wrong off the top of my head; Queen didn't perform Fat Bottom Girls on their first US tour; they played the US in 1974 and FBG wasn't written until late 1977, Queen actually had 2 managers prior to Paul Prenter, Freddie's last partner was never a butler, and Freddie found out he had AIDS *after* Live Aid.  Oh, and that whole "first time playing Bohemian Rhapsody on the radio" event actually happened quite differently than depicted.

Answer (score 15):

Well, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_Aid), the answer is different.

> Nearly seven hours into the concert in London, Bob Geldof enquired how much money had been raised so far; he was told about £1.2 million. He is said to have been sorely disappointed by the amount and marched to the BBC commentary position. **Pumped up further by a performance by Queen** which he later called "absolutely amazing", Geldof gave an interview in which he used the word "fuck". Conducting the interview, BBC presenter David Hepworth had attempted to provide a postal address to which potential donations could be sent; Geldof interrupted him in mid-flow and shouted "Fuck the address, let's get the numbers". Although the phrase "give us your fucking money" has passed into folklore, Geldof has stated that it was never uttered. Private Eye magazine made great humorous capital out of this outburst, emphasising Geldof's Irish accent which meant the profanities were heard as "fock" or "focking". **After the outburst, donations increased to £300 per second.**

Emphasis is mine.

Comment: 'Private Eye magazine made great humorous capital out of this outburst, emphasising Geldof's Irish accent which meant the profanities were heard as "fock" or "focking"' - interesting... I would've thought it was the English accent that pronounces it "fock" or "focking"... Though Geldof does have that posh "from-nowhere" Irish accent...